# SQlite Table not getting created,but DB got created in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android Programming and I am kind of lost with the SQLite table creation.So in my app,user enters three values(`Intime`,`OutTime` and `Date`) which should be saved to the table "updatedata" under Record.db
Here is my code for that:

```
public class Inserted_DB{

public static final String dbname="Record" ;
public static final String table="updatedata";
public static final String in="InTime";
public static final String out="OutTime";
public static final String date="Date";
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context ctx;
helper help;

public Inserted_DB(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    help=new helper(ctx);
}


private static class helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public helper(Context ctx)

    {
        super(ctx,dbname,null,2);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       try
       {
           String sql = "create table "+ table  +"(InTime text,OutTime text,Date text)";
           db.execSQL(sql);

       }
       catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
 public void update(String In1,String out1,String date1,Context ct)
 {
   db=help.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues con=new ContentValues();
   con.put(in,In1);
   con.put(out,out1);
   con.put(date,date1);
   db.insert(table,null,con);
   db.close();
  }}
```

I am just calling the update function from another class(Update Tracker) and the snippet is below:

```
            String in_db=txtTime.getText().toString();
            String date_db=txtDate.getText().toString();
            String out_db=txtTime2.getText().toString();
            Inserted_DB db1=new Inserted_DB(getBaseContext());
            db1.update(in_db,out_db,date_db,UpdateTracker.this);
```

DB getting created but the table is not.I used DDMS File explorer to navigate to the respective path *data/data/mypackage.com.myapp/databases* and could see the DB created.Using sqlite3 when I query ".`databases`",its showing the DB name but when I query ".tables" its empty.

[Updated Snap for DB getting created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bf7j.png)

What am I missing?Could you guys help me out to find a solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try deleting the database and re run.
Check this if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: Note your database file name is `Record`. The `Record.db` seen in your DDMS is some older, empty file.

Comment: I un-installed the app and installed again.Also I cleared the app data.But unfortunately its not getting created

Comment: Anyway, your helper declares the name as `Record` and that's the file you should be looking at with sqlite3, not `Record.db` that is created by some other code not shown here.

Comment: Oh I just thought .db extension will be added automatically to the DB name what we give in the code.Thanks for your input laalto.Now its clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues is because of space while creating table

Just Replace this

```
create table "+ table  +" (InTime text,OutTime text,Date text)
```

instead of

```
create table "+ table  +"(InTime text,OutTime text,Date text)
```

**EDIT**

also change database name

```
public static final String dbname="Record.db";
```

instead of

```
public static final String dbname="Record" ;
```

Comment: use this example for following standard database implementations : https://github.com/ddpatel2606/AndroidSqliteInsertTime

Comment: Thank for the instant suggestion. As you told,I just used this modified query in the respective line.                                                                   String sql = "create table "+ table +" (InTime text,OutTime text,Date text)";    But still its not getting created.

Comment: Whitespace does not matter here.